# If a variable is null then show another variable

Tags: php, variables

I have two variables: var1 & var2. I want to display var1 default, but if var1 is empty or null, show var2. regardless of whether or not it has var2 value.

Comment: welcome and please use English ..

Comment: Always showing a variable that may not be set is not a good solution, Can't you just show var1 is it exists or, var 2 if it exists or nothing if neither exist? That is a much more robust solution than possibly using unset variables.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
echo empty($var1)? $var2 : $var1;
```

Comment: haah exactly the same as mine XD

Comment: :D I know, but I assure you I hadn't seen yours before posting mine!

Comment: haha I don't mind anyway, I'm here to help, not get the praise ;P

Comment: nice to hear that :) I like getting more reputation, but at the same time I don't cheat ;)

Comment: You dont need both isset and !empty()  if it is not set then it will be empty

Comment: You missed a ! out of your function you are checking !empty() but in your example you have empty()

Comment: I have changed the variables, check it carefully

Comment: @Anigel, I think you're missing something. I'm not doing `!empty()` because I've changed the two variables' places. It says `is var1 empty? Yes: show var2. No: show var1'`

Comment: @mavili I was on about in your codepad that you gave to demonstrate why you thought codepad was required

Answer (score 4):

It can be done using [ternary operator `?:`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary) with [`Isset()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php) function.

```
<?php
   echo (isset($var1) && !empty($var1) ? $var1 : $var2);
?>
```

That should do the trick :)

Comment: You don't need both isset and !empty()  if it is not set then it will be empty

Comment: `empty` will explicit check `isset`